# View character role and race in Nethack?

Tags: nethack

I can see the Rank on the status line, so I think I could guess the role, but is there a command to list the current character's details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're playing on vanilla Nethack, according to the [guidebook](http://www.nethack.org/v343/Guidebook.html#_TOCentry_7), <kbd>^X</kbd> seems to be the command you're looking for. (On most keyboards, this means <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.)